# Ruby - rails - destroy instance variable after ajax

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I destroy instance variable after completing one ajax call. In my app data is returned via ajax and often new calls are made, some values from previous call are returned mixed with some new values. Is that something considered design flow? Or shall just move head by finding a way to destroy the veritable/values?

Example controller -

```
    def something
    @result = Stuff.find_all_by_requestor_name
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :partial => 'list'}
    format.js
    end
    return @result 
    end
```

I have noticed few times that ajax requests mix up values. Am I mistaking big here?

Comment: what instance variables are you talking about exactly ?

Comment: @Abid - Hey Abid, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your questions is concerned, There is no way for the instance variables to survive between calls, each http-call is independent of the other calls and variables don't live till the next call. But I have noticed something weird in your code below

```
def something
    @result = Stuff.find_all_by_requestor_name
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :partial => 'list'}
        format.js
    end
    return @result 
end
```

Looking at this code above, I don't see why are you returning a value from a controller function that gets an AJAX request. I think what you wanted to was the follwing

```
def something
    @result = Stuff.find_all_by_requestor_name
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :partial => 'list'}
        format.js { render :json => @result }
    end
end
```

you should `render` inside the `format.js` block rather than returning in the end. Hope that helps